# explorer.exe randomly throws numerous "This file does not have an app associated with it for performing this action" errors

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11

I'm using Windows 11 Version 22H2. At seemingly random times (not necessarily when I'm doing any action in particular), Windows throws up ten plus error windows with this message:

> This file does not have an app associated with it for performing this action. Please install an app or, if one is already installed, create an association in the Default Apps Settings page.

[image: error message]

I'm not doing anything in the File Explorer when this happens. Sometimes it's in a browser, sometimes it's Notepad, sometimes in Office, and sometimes it's when I come back to my computer in the morning after not touching it all night.

I looked in the Event Viewer system logs and don't see any Explorer.exe errors (or any other errors, for that matter) in the Application, Security, or System logs.

What could be causing this? How do I debug it?

---

EDIT: Following this comment from [John](https://superuser.com/users/1079976/john):

> Open Control Panel, Security and Maintenance, pull down Maintenance and look at Reliability History. There may be Explorer stopped working errors there. If so, go from there.

I checked and there are no Explorer.exe errors listed today, or anytime in the past couple of weeks.

Comment: Open Control Panel, Security and Maintenance, pull down Maintenance and look at Reliability History. There may be Explorer stopped working errors there. If so, go from there.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to post this as an answer, but this post on the MS community site suggests this could be a OneDrive issue https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/explorerexe-file-association-error-after-onedrive/c443db9b-d9c8-44fd-8aab-4213536b85a7

Answer (score 1):

Two things to check: check what is opening the files -- look in Task Manger on the Details tab for any unknown process, or any process using CPU or I/O steadily that you **did not** start. One likely offender is the [Search Indexer](https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-11-index-faster-search-results/). If you try to index the contents of *all* files, the Indexer could be attempting to open some odd files. Restrict indexing to known file types, such as DOCX and TXT. Also malware could be attempting to open files, so perform a full malware scan.

Also, check and repair the operating system using [DISM and SFC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/using-system-file-checker-in-windows-365e0031-36b1-6031-f804-8fd86e0ef4ca), if you cannot find a process causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Having the same issue.  Check if it's a scheduled task by doing this: Next time it happens, open task scheduler and look in task history to see if something recently launched. (Task history is disabled by default, so you have to have enabled history beforehand). My suspicion is Adobe Acrobat Update Task.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me and I believe it was because of having the Adobe cloud sync folder open while my account logged out, which caused my computer to lose access to the cloud and the error message popped up. Maybe there is a similar cloud service causing to the issue?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).